# Probability of there being a bullet in the chamber

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, word-problem

Suppose we have three $6$-chambered guns:

- The first has no bullets.
- The second has one bullet.
- The third has two bullets in consecutive chambers.

The cylinder advances automatically as the trigger is pulled. A man grabs a revolver at random, aims it at him, pulls the trigger $t$ times, and no shot is fired. He then aims at your head and pulls the trigger once. What is the probability you are shot?

Comment: The man "grabs a revolver at random" but what is the distribution? Uniform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**:

Let $X$ denote the number of shots needed for appearing a bullet if at random a revolver is picked and is shooted several times.

Then $X$ takes values in $\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6,\infty\right\}$

Note that there are $18$ chambers in total having equal probability
to be chosen for the first shot, and it is not really difficult to find that:

$P\left(X=1\right)=\frac{3}{18}$

$P\left(X=2\right)=P\left(X=3\right)=P\left(X=4\right)=P\left(X=5\right)=\frac{2}{18}$

$P\left(X=6\right)=\frac{1}{18}$

$P\left(X=\infty\right)=\frac{6}{18}$

Based on this you can find $P(X=t+1\mid X>t)$.

Observe that this probability takes value $0$ if $t>5$ so the task can be completed by finding expressions for $t\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

I leave the rest to you.

Comment: i'm struggling to understand your answer, could you possible show how I would obtain the answer for t=1 using your way please.

Comment: I'm more confused as to how you set up the problem, i.e how you calculate P(X=2) and probability (X=infinity). I understand for x = 1 is number of bullets(3) divided by number of chambers.

Comment: Also, how do you know that you should combine them making it out of 18 instead of multiplying each one out of 6 by 1/3?

Comment: For $t=1$ we find $P(X=2\mid X>1)=P(X=2)/P(X>1)=2/(18-3)=2/15$. Note that there are $15$ empty chambers and exactly $2$ of them are followed by a chamber that contains a bullet. Concerning your last comment: it is not so much a matter of "knowing" but more a (nice) way to approach the problem. Instead of looking at $3$ guns we are looking at $18$ equiprobable chambers.